# How do you ORA - 00907: Missing right parenthesis

Tags: oracle, ora-00907

```
Create TABLE Emp_test1
(Employee_id Number (6)
CONSTRAINT employee_id NOT NULL,
FIRST_NAME Varchar2 (20),
LAST_NAME Varchar2 (25)
CONSTRAINT Last_name NOT NULL,
Email Varchar2 (25)
CONSTRAINT Email NOT NULL,
PHONE_NUMBER Varchar2 (20)
HIRE_DATE Date 
CONSTRAINT Hire_date NOT NULL,
Job_id Varchar2 (10)
CONSTRAINT Job_id NOT NULL,
Salary Number (8,2),
Commission_pct Number (2,2),
Manager_id NUmber (6),
Department_id Number (4)),
```

Why do I keep getting an `ORA 00907` missing right parenthesis on the hire_date line?

Answer (score 4):

You've lost a comma after `PHONE_NUMBER Varchar2 (20),`

```
Create TABLE Emp_test1
(Employee_id Number (6)
CONSTRAINT employee_id NOT NULL,
FIRST_NAME Varchar2 (20),
LAST_NAME Varchar2 (25)
CONSTRAINT Last_name NOT NULL,
Email Varchar2 (25)
CONSTRAINT Email NOT NULL,
PHONE_NUMBER Varchar2 (20),
HIRE_DATE Date 
CONSTRAINT Hire_date NOT NULL,
Job_id Varchar2 (10)
CONSTRAINT Job_id NOT NULL,
Salary Number (8,2),
Commission_pct Number (2,2),
Manager_id NUmber (6),
Department_id Number (4));
```